# javascript toggle needs to stay

Tags: javascript, html

hi guys i need some help with javascript,
i have a toggle function for my text, waht you can see on www.jasperscheper.nl
but i want to make the text stay when you double click on over mij and home.

this is my code:

```js
var bannerText1 = document.getElementById('bannertext1');
var bannerText2 = document.getElementById('bannertext2');
var displayedBannerText = 1;

function toggleBannerText() {
  if(displayedBannerText == 1) {
    // Switch to bannertext 2
    bannerText1.className += ' hidebannertext';
    displayedBannerText = 2;
    bannertext2.className = 'welkom';
  } else {
    bannertext2.className += ' hidebannertext';
    displayedBannerText = 1;
    bannerText1.className = 'welkom';
  }
 }
```

```html
<li class="knop" >    
  <button class="button" href="#"onclick="toggleBannerText()"> <h3>Home</h3></button> 
</li>
<li class="knop"> 
  <button class="button" onclick="toggleBannerText()" href="#"><h3>Over mij</h3></button>
</li>
```

thanks in advance,

Jasper Scheper.

Comment: We don't want to visit your page, create a pen or a fiddle

Comment: how do i create it?

Comment: There is a built-in snippet in question/answer edition for executing web code.

Comment: You go to codepen.com and you create a new pen, or you go to jsfiddle.com and you save your code there, and post the link here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You are calling the function `toggleBannerText()` every time there is a click on any of the buttons, There is no where the button's click events are distinguished, So every click assumes you need to show other text than the one shown.

**Solution:** Change your HTML to pass a parameter into the function saying which section it wants to show. Eg: `toggleBannerText('Home')`

```
<li class="knop" >    
<button class="button" href="#"onclick="toggleBannerText('Home')"> <h3>Home</h3></button> 
</li>

<li class="knop"> 
<button class="button" onclick="toggleBannerText('Over')" href="#"><h3>Over mij</h3>
</button>  <!-- There was a typo you had a </a> here I changed it -->
</li>
```

Now change your function to accept the parameter and show that particular Text .

```
function toggleBannerText(section) {
  if(section === "Over") {
    // Switch to bannertext 2
    bannerText1.className = 'hidebannertext';      // I have removed the +  
    bannertext2.className = 'welkom';
  } 
  else if (section === "Home"){
    bannertext2.className = 'hidebannertext';      // + has been removed 
    bannerText1.className = 'welkom';
   }
  else{
    // none of the two buttons were clicked.
  }
}
```

---

*`I have tested this code against your site and its working fine`*

Comment: thanks for your answer. i will try the code ! thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi man, your answer does not seem to work for me :( do you know how i can fix it?

Comment: @JasperScheper I am 100% sure It does.. Because I tested it in your site itself. You need to change your HTML and your Function.. make sure you got all the changes done as suggested

Comment: can you help me with what i have to change exactely? i am changing the code in phpStorm but it does not work... maybe i am doing something wrong

Comment: In my answer I have shown you to change the HTML a little bit that is adding a parameter into the function call. And also to modify your function logic to work with the passed input parameter. It's all there in my answer.. that is it, No more chabges required other than that